# Starting phpMyAdmin gives mbstring extension is missing error even php-mbstring is installed in Fedora 27

Tags: fedora, php, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin after installed MySQL 5.7 and PHP 7.1.12 in Fedora 27, all installed using rpm packages via dnf command. But when I started phpMyAdmin on the web browser using localhost/phpmyadmin/, I got the "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration." error.

As suggested by tons of answers on the Internet, I also installed:

- php-mbstring (mine is php-mbstring-7.1.12-1.fc27.x86_64)
- php-gettext (mine is php-common-7.1.12-1.fc27.x86_64)

which matches the PHP version: php-7.1.12-1.fc27.x86_64.

and I restarted httpd (the default version in Fedora 27), but the error still occurred. What should I do? Do I have to modify some part of the /etc/php.ini?

Comment: You can run `php -i |grep ^extension_dir` to determine where those modules should be located. If you are still stuck, then update your question with the output of that directory, so your system configuration is known.  You do indeed to modify your php.ini in order or at least verify your PHP configuration is loading extensions from the correct location.

Comment: [PHP 5.6 - mbstring extension is missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/780112/php-5-6-mbstring-extension-is-missing) I suspect you will find that the module is located in one directory and your extension directory is something else entirely.  Which of course means mbstring won't ever be loaded.  You might also verify `extension=mbstring` isn't commented out within php.ini

Comment: @Ramhound When I run php -i | grep ^extension_dir, I got a load or errors, starting with "Failed loading ./opcache.so: ./opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", then "PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './bcmath.so' -- " ... and so on. I found that even MySQLi cannot work with PHP. Seems the configuration was all messed up.

Answer (score 1):

From [Remi's repository blog](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/11/17/Fedora-27-changes-in-http-and-php).

> 5. Known issues
>
> 5.1. Configuration change
>
> After a configuration change, or after a new extension installation, it is now required to restart the php-fpm service.

Run these commands

```
systemctl restart php-fpm 
systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: What is "Remi's repository blog"?

Comment: I think Line_VTY refers to https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/11/17/Fedora-27-changes-in-http-and-php

Comment: BTW, probably simpler to "dnf install phpMyAdmin", which will pull all needed dependencies.